# How to fix "Failed to fetch libreoffice-common.xxx.deb"?

Tags: apt, gnome, 22.10

When trying to install Libre Office on Ubuntu 2022.10, **all packages download successfully, *except*** package libreoffice-common, which keeps failing with error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-common_7.4.2%7erc3-0ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

> Side note: Kinda strange to see a `%` character in the package name of the error message above - could this be related?

Oddly enough, it happens only with package libreoffice-common, and neither `apt-get update` nor `--fix-missing` has any effect. Completely removing libre office had no effect. Neither did the commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Question now is, what's wrong, and how can it be fixed?
You advise is very much appreciated, Thank you.

**Edit:**
`apt policy libreoffice-common` prints:

```
libreoffice-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.4.2~rc3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:7.4.2~rc3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: There's something you are not telling us, because the package in 22.10 has version 1:7.4.2~rc3-0ubuntu1 https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/kinetic/main/base/libreoffice-common Please add the output of `apt policy libreoffice-common` to your question.

Comment: The `~` in the package name is encoded as `%7e` since `~` [should not be used in web adresses](https://jkorpela.fi/tilde.html), so the `%` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for your help. Question edited. One more thing I've omitted is that the system was originally installed with Ubuntu 2018.04 (IIRC), so this could have been broken (and gone unnoticed) already years ago.

Comment: @mook765 Thank you very much for the clarification.